# Why is it incorrect to say "I lonely walked around the park."?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

And how do I say it right?

This should be an explanation:

[image: Image of text reading: "Some words end in 'ly' but they are not adverbs. **Friendly** is an example. Friendly is an adjective. We can say 'She is friendly' but not 'She talks friendly'. There is no adverb for friendly, but we can say 'She talks in a friendly way'. **Elderly** and **lonely** are also adjectives, not adverbs. **Kindly** and **early** are adjectives and adverbs.]

but I still don't understand that why does the sentence "I lonely walked around the park" does not make any sense

Comment: What you quoted makes it clear. *Lonely* is an adjective, not an adverb. An adjective can modify a noun but it can't modify a verb.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Would you say “I happy walked around the park” or “I young walked around the park”, substituting different adjectives for _lonely_?

Comment: That helped me actually. Well then "I walked around the park alone" should be right? I was just thinking why does that not make no sense but I think I get it now It's fine.

Comment: @Olgierd:  As a footnote, lonely and alone aren't synonyms.  You can be alone, yet not lonely.

Comment: Just to note that the construction "I lonely walked around the park" would be totally fine in a poetic or literary setting. This kind of usage has history to it. You could also say "I walked around the park lonely" instead of "... alone", but as Janus says, it has a different meaning. Still grammatically kosher though.

Comment: E.g., “I have hours, only lonely” / “My love is vengeance” / “That's never free” — “Behind Blue Eyes” by The Who, lyrics courtesy of [Songfacts](https://www.songfacts.com/lyrics/the-who/behind-blue-eyes).

Answer (score 4):

You actually *can* say that, but it sounds very poetic/old fashioned rather than like natural, everyday speech and you probably need some extra punctuation to clarify for modern speakers.

As the passage that you quoted explains, *lonely* is an adjective, not an adverb, so it can only describe a noun, not a verb (that is, it can describe a person, place, or thing, but can't describe an action). This means *lonely* cannot describe the way the person in your sentence is walking, but it could describe the person.

The problem with the sentence as-written is the placement of the word *lonely*. English usually puts adjectives in front of the noun they modify (red rose, beautiful dreamer, happy children, etc.), so without any other clues we are going to want to connect *lonely* with the word the word that follows it. In this case, that word is *walked*, but this doesn't work because it's not a noun.

We can "fix" this by interpreting *lonely* as an attributive clause. Attributive clauses modify the noun that immediately precedes them. Usually they're more than one word, but they don't have to be.

As I mentioned, this will sound poetical, and actually parallels some existing poetry:

> When, in disgrace with fortune and men’s eyes,
>   I all alone beweep my outcast state
>   —[William Shakespeare, *Sonnet 29*](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45090/sonnet-29-when-in-disgrace-with-fortune-and-mens-eyes)
>
> Soon as the portals ope; **I lonely tread**
>   The sacred paths conductive thro' the choir
>   —[Rev. Alsop, *A Description of the Choir at St. Peter's Church*, 1738](https://books.google.com/books?id=VEodAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22i%20lonely%20tread%20the%20sacred%20paths%22&pg=PA437#v=onepage&q=%22i%20lonely%20tread%20the%20sacred%20paths%22&f=false)
>
> Thus wrapped in gloom **I lonely walk**
>   Life's dark and dreary way
>   —[Joshua Ross, "My Ruling Star", 1855](https://books.google.com/books?id=r-d-VMCTtqMC&lpg=PA132&dq=%22i%20lonely%20walk%22&pg=PA132#v=onepage&q=%22i%20lonely%20walk%22&f=false)

As you can tell from the dates, it's also a very old-fashioned construction (there are other examples, but all that I've found are at least a hundred years old), so this won't be the first interpretation that most modern speakers will guess. We can make it a bit clearer by enclosing *lonely* in commas:

> I, lonely, walked around the park.

However, if you want to have a more straightforward sentence that everyone will understand, you probably need to reword to something like

> [Feeling] Lonely, I walked around the park.

or

> I walked around the park, all alone.